# Silverlight - How should I implement drag in canvas?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7

I am building a little app for the Windows Phone 7 (Silverlight 3) which allows the user to add objects to the screen and drag them around.
My class is defined as the following:

```
 public class Frame
    {
        public double Height{ get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public Uri Image { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush BgColor { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is about my approach on how to implement this. I am fairly new to SilverLight (have experience in WPF) and am finding out the things in WPF that are missing in SL3 (commanding, for instance). 
As I see it I could:
a) use a `ListBox` with a Canvas in the `ItemsPanelTemplate` and bind it to a `ObservableCollection<Frame>`. In WPF would use commands in the DataTemplate for the events involved in the Drag/Drop. But there are no commands in SL3.
b) As the user adds a new object, I could create an instance of `Frame` and then wire the necessary events. How can I apply a DataTemplate in this case?

Which route should I take? How to overcome the challenges describe above? Any better suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the GestureListerner/GestureReceiver in the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/52297).
The source comes with a sample which demonstrates dragging an object.

Alternatively, look at the [MultiTouch Behaviour created by Laurent Bugnion](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/07/04/multitouch-behavior-for-windows-phone-7-videos-wp7dev.aspx) which also enables dragging.

Comment: Matt, thanks for your answer. I believe I know how to do the actual dragging. My question regarding my approach. Should I take route "a" or "b". Or perhaps use a templated ListBox and attach the events using the VisualTreeHelper...?

Comment: Laurent's solution is very interesting if you have the object to be dragged already in place in design-time. In my case users create these objects themselves. So how would I apply the behavior after they are added?